# 1992 Honda Accord LX Running hot, Fans not kicking on and heater not working

Tags: honda, accord, overheating

I have a 1992 Honda accord LX. So first on what i changed was my Radiator and two of the hose's. And the car is still running hot. The fans arent kicking on when the car gets hot. But comes on when I Turn the car off. Also my heater isnt getting hot anymore. Could it be a Thermostat? I didnt start having this problem until i changed the Heater core to valve hose and my top radiator hose witch both of them hoses blew a hole in. Please any help will be greatful. Car only has 128,000 miles on it and alot of the stuff is all orgenal parts.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

From your description it sounds like you might have two problems. It does sound as though your thermostat needs changed (overheating).

The second thing you need to check is if the relays to your fans are working. Check your relays by switching them out with other ones to see if they are working. You might be able to check your fans by turning on the A/C as well. If that doesn't work, apply power directly to the fans to see if they will power up. I don't believe your Accord has two temperature senders, but it might. If it does have two, one would feed the gauge on the desk and the other would tell the ECU what temperature the engine is, which would turn the fans on when it gets hot enough. You might be able to plug in a reader to see what the ECU believes is the temperature, though with it being a 92 I don't know if that's readily available.

Not sure why you'd be changing the radiator before the thermostat. The radiator costs a wee bit more. Plus, your description of the heat not working is fairly typical of a thermostat problem.

Comment: The reason I changed the radiator is because I thought it was leaking but I soon realized that wasn’t the issue so now it has a new one so I won’t have to worry about that anytime soon